# add to array and return boolean

Tags: java, arrays

I would like to add an object to an array and return true if the array is not full so the item can be added, and false if the array is full of items.

What I have right now I believe is only partially correct.

```
private Object[] theList;
//constructors omitted
@Override
public boolean add(Object toAdd) {
    for(int i=0; i < theList.length;i++){
        if(toAdd != null){                  
            theList[i] = toAdd; 
        }         
    }
    return true;
}
```

I think using an element counter would be the right way to go to keep track
of the number of element currently in the array.

The method is overridden from an interface, if that matters.

Not sure if it is returning true based on the on the loop and conditions or just returning true no matter what.

Comment: better to use `Collections` `ArrayList Class` if You don't know the length of Data Array at the time of Excution of Program.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to find the first `null` value in your array, and if such a value exists, replace it with your `toAdd` object and return true.

The code for that would be something along the lines of:

```
private Object[] theList;

@Override
public boolean add(Object toAdd) {
    for(int i=0; i < theList.length; i++) {
        if(theList[i] == null){                  
            theList[i] = toAdd;

            return true;
        }         
    }

    return false;
}
```

If you also want to return `false` in case your `toAdd` object is `null`, for performance reasons, you should check for that *before* looping over the array:

```
@Override
public boolean add(Object toAdd) {
    if (toAdd != null) {
        for(int i=0; i < theList.length; i++) {
            if(theList[i] == null){                  
                theList[i] = toAdd;

                return true;
            }         
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Obviously it's more convenient to use an `ArrayList` instead.

Comment: Yes ArrayList is more convenient but my teacher wants to challenge us with using Arrays instead.

Answer (score 0):

You Have not initialized Your `object[]` ObjectArray `theList`. So, It won't be able to add new element to this.

> Here I am Giving a Solution For Your Problem Using `ArrayList` Class. `ArrayList` is an auto Growable Array Increased Its Size Dynamically at Runtime.

```
 private ArrayList<Object> theList = new ArrayList<>(); //A Auto Growable Array Increased Its Size Dynamically at Runtime.
    //constructors omitted
    @Override
    public boolean add(Object toAdd) {
         if(toAdd != null){                  
            theList.add(toAdd); 
            return true; //returns true id Object is added to theList.
         }else
             return false; //returns false if Object is Null .
    }
```

> Code to Get ArrayList Size

```
theList.size() //Use This Code to know the Size of Array List.
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to initialize the array. Otherwise it will return you a Null Pointer Exception. Here is my code. Hope it will help...

```
class Demo{
    static boolean result;
    public static void main(String args[]){

        Object ob= new Object();
        result = A.add(ob);

        System.out.println(result);

        Object ob1= new Object();
        result = A.add(ob1);
        System.out.println(result);

    }

}

class A{
    static private Object[] theList = new Object[10];
    public static boolean add(Object ob){
        boolean result = false;
            for(int i=0; i<theList.length; i++){
                if(ob != null){
                    theList[i] = ob;
                    result = true;
                }
            }
        return result;  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Default value of array of objects is `null`. So that you can check whether an element is null or not.

```
for(int i=0:i<theList.length;i++) {
   if(theList[i] == null && toAdd!=null)  // Element is null or not
       theList[i]=toAdd;
       return true;   
}
return false;
```

if element is null then array is still empty and you can put value there and return `true`.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using an ArrayList as they are expandable and do not have a set size. So whenever you add something it just grows the ArrayList instead of changing the value of an index.

Answer (score -1):

Edited second time, another solution as per suggestions by peer contributers. I have also posted understanding of the questions in the comments. Please suggest if there is any aberration in the understanding.

Kindly see one possible solution:

```
public class TestCode {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    /*
     * Question: 
     * I would like to add an object to an array and 
     * return true if the array is not full so the item can be added, 
     * and false if the array is full of items.
     */
    Object[] objects = new Object [] {1, 2, null, 4, 5, null , 7};
    SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass(objects);
    // just for sake of passing;
    Integer toAdd = 10;
    boolean isNotFull = someClass.add(toAdd);

    System.out.println("Array after adding: "+Arrays.toString(objects));
    System.out.println("Array is Not full:"+isNotFull);

    isNotFull = someClass.add(toAdd);
    System.out.println("Array after adding: "+Arrays.toString(objects));
    System.out.println("Array is Not full:"+isNotFull);

    isNotFull = someClass.add(toAdd);
    System.out.println("Array after adding: "+Arrays.toString(objects));
    System.out.println("Array is Not full:"+isNotFull);



}

}

class SomeClass {
private Object[] theList;
//constructors omitted

public SomeClass(Object[] theList) {
    this.theList = theList; 
}
/*
 * returns true if array is not full and element is inserted.
 */
public boolean add(Object toAdd) {
    int i = 0;
    boolean flag = false; // if flag is true, the array is not empty
    // question says: 
    // "I would like to add an object to an array"
    // means we need to first find an empty slot to insert in the array
    for( ; i < theList.length;i++){
        // to check if there is any first empty space in the array
        // so that the element can be inserted.
        // (finding the empty slot
        if(theList[i] == null){
            // to check if elements passed as an aargument itself is false
            if (toAdd!=null) {
                theList[i] = toAdd;
                break;
            }

        }

    }

    for (;i <theList.length; i++) {
         if(theList[i] == null){
            flag = true;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
}
```

**Solution:**
Output of the code as I get:

```
Array after adding: [1, 2, 10, 4, 5, null, 7]
Array is Not full:true
Array after adding: [1, 2, 10, 4, 5, 10, 7]
Array is Not full:false
Array after adding: [1, 2, 10, 4, 5, 10, 7]
Array is Not full:false
```

Comment: @VikrantKashyap it's not my question. I just answered. I know it's kind of absurd but just giving answer.

Comment: 1) What ternary operator? 2) `length` will return the capacity of the array, regardless of its contents.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen changed the code. earlier misread the question.

Comment: Your code (just like OP's code) would instantly fill all positions of the array with the first value that you try to add.

Comment: @VikrantKashyap changed the solution. Kindly up vote. And for your solution it will stop copying once it has seen a null value.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen yes it should. It will stop copying elements  otherwise. He has not mentioned it should stop copying elements of its empty.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen there might be difference in logic but wrong. Earlier had misread the question. Kindly up vote what you had down voted.

Comment: @VikrantKashyap The array is most likely initialized by the constructor (hence OP added the comment `//constructors omitted`).

Comment: @VikrantKashyap please be polite. You are not the only Java developer in the world.

Comment: @VikrantKashyap i agree stackoverflow is all about giving solutions. There is nothing begging. It does not matter to me. May be it matters to you and hence such arrogant reply. If you are really interested in giving solution you would help other people who are giving solutions as well. Not rant like this. Now take this. Dont mess with me, keep your arrogance with you. Its big world out there.

Comment: In response to your request for an upvote. I'm very sorry, but your code 1) will not compile (`flag` not initialized); and 2) is logically incorrect because, on every invocation, it will just fill the entire array with the value being added.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Please see the change in code. I want to find solution to this. its not about upvote anymore. Kindly see the change in logic and code. Help me if i am wrong. I have run the code and also output is printed. If this is still not correct then there is something wrong with the understanding.

Comment: I think we indeed have a different understanding. IMO, the method should also return `true` the second time you add `10`, i.e. it should return `true` if the new object was successfully added, but I agree that the phrasing of the question is indeed a little bit ambiguous.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen second time it returned false because the question says it should return true only array is not full. After second element is added it's not true. So per that don't you think it's okay ? M

Comment: Like I said: the question is a little bit ambiguous. As I read it, it should return true if the array is not full _before_ adding the element, hence the phrasing "return true if the array is not full so the item can be added".

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen ok then. Let the question poster come with a revision if he thinks we are close. And thanks for the help. Your input helped me refine the solution.